# Spinners takes more time to load a view In Android fragment

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am using more than 5 spinners in one of fragment class, all spinners loading from String array list, When I called this fragment from another fragment It takes two to three seconds to load a view, This is happening only when I am using static data (Predefined String array) Here I have added my code, I am setting all adapters in `OnViewCreated` method

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and cities array
        adapterCity = new SpinnerViewAdapter(c);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and states array
        adapterState = new SpinnerViewAdapter(c);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and countries array
        adapterCountry = new SpinnerViewAdapter(c);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and heightFt array
        adapterHeightFt = new SpinnerViewAdapter(c);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and Height in Inch  array
        adapterHeightIn = new SpinnerViewAdapter(c);

        sCity.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        sCountry.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
        sState.setAdapter(adapterState);
        sHeight1.setAdapter(adapterHeightFt);
        sHeight2.setAdapter(adapterHeightIn);

        adapterCity.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListCity));
        adapterCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListCountry));
        adapterState.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListState));
        adapterHeightFt.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListHeightFt));
        adapterHeightIn.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListHeightIn));
```

I tried to add using threads, also I tried background tasks to add list of items into the spinners but nothing works for me, Anyone suggest me a better option to avoid the loading time ?

Comment: you are first set the adapters and after loading data to them? Why? Also another thing is that you are converting Lists to Arrays. The question is why don't you directly get an array?

Comment: If your list is static than it will better to define them in string.xml file

Comment: @matrix I changed it Thanks :-), But it will not solve this

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I moved my static items to string.xml, also I tried to add the items from onPostexecute in AsyncTask now view loaded properly like other fragments, but the list items only takes few seconds to load, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I have added that as an answer please accept that as answer so that it will help others too

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I tried your comment it doesn't reduced the view loading time because list items has lot of data, after that I moved adding list items to onPostExecute then view loaded as usual, that's why I didn't accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my static string array items to `string.xml`, also I tried to add all spinner items from `onPostexecute` in `AsyncTask` now view loaded as usual like other fragments, Here I have added my working code.

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        adapterCity.addAll(ListCity);
        adapterCountry.addAll(ListCountry);
        adapterState.addAll(ListState);
        adapterHeightFt.addAll(ListHeightFt);
        adapterHeightIn.addAll(ListHeightIn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you spinner list is static than move all the list in `string.xml` layout file it will work